# Clean way to call a Vex dialog box to avoid code repetition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm using the [vex dialog library](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/) basically as a replacement for standard alert, confirm, prompt etc boxes and I have been using them like this for example:

```
$('.js-edit-cancel').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    vex.dialog.buttons.YES.text = t('Yes');
    vex.dialog.buttons.NO.text = t('No');

    vex.dialog.confirm({
        message: t('Are you sure you want to cancel?'),
        callback: function(value) {

            if (value) {
              // Some code here...
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Now whilst this works, it starts to become a little repetitive when you are using the dialog boxes for several things.

Ideally I could simply add **HTML5** `data-*` attributes to any element I wanted one on, something like `data-confirm-box` or `data-prompt-box`; however problem with this method is I also need to be able to set custom messages rather than always having it set to *Are you sure you want to cancel?* as well as being able to supply a callback function to run; I guess technically I could supply this data as extra `data-*` attributes, but it just seems a bit messy to me.

Then I thought I could keep doing `click` events for each element I wanted it on and passing in the custom message, but I guess I would also have to pass in a callback this way and then this would end up with having two code blocks each time you want to use one; the `click` event handler and then the callback function.

Is there any cleaner way to do what I want to do - be able to set a custom message as well as an optional callback / custom code each time I want a confirmation box?

The library itself is vanilla **JavaScript** but I'm also using **jQuery** as you can see so I'm happy using either.

Comment: Sounds like you know how to do this...and are simply looking for somone to layout the best approach, which really only you could do by testing some different ones yourself. We don't know near as much about your various use cases as you do. Whole question then is really about opinions and therefore not really answerable or on-topic

Comment: @charlietfl It's not really about opinions as I am asking if there is a cleaner way than I have already thought of to be able to pass a custom message as well as a callback, if there are multiple ways this can be achieved then all the better :)

Comment: Sure there are numerous ways and that's part of the issue. You already outlined several of them yourself. But personal preferences will creep into what anyone might consider "best"

Comment: You could store all messages in a single object to cut down a lot of string duplication, perhaps same for button text

Comment: Would also look at using a wrapper function that takes an options object as argument...then extend the default options of `vex()` using `$.extend` for each use

Comment: @charlietfl Personal preferences could creep into the answers to many questions - there is more than one way to skin a cat :) Thanks for the ideas as well.

Comment: right...and it sounds like you know how to do this...and need to simply build some test approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may declare and use a unified function(let's say `showDialog(type, options)`) passing in the ***type*** of dialog and a custom ***options*** object:

```
function showDialog(type, options) {
    if (typeof type !== 'string' 
        || ['alert','prompt','confirm','open'].indexOf(type) === -1) {
        throw new Error('Wrong dialog type!');
    }
    // You can specify your own buttons if you want more options than just OK or Cancel. 
    // If you simply want to change the labels, you can override the default options

    // You can also specify a static message text for a certain dialog type
    vex.dialog[type](options);
}

// Approximate usage:
...
$('.js-edit-cancel').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    showDialog('confirm', {
        message: t('Are you sure you want to cancel?')
    });

});
...

$('.some_element').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    showDialog('alert', {
        message: t("You don't have permission on this action!")
    });

});
...

$('.some_other_element').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    showDialog('open', {
        message: t('Select date and time:'),
        callback: function(data) {

            if (data) {
              // Some code here...
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! :)